# jQuery .each not returning per-item data as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

If I output the value of next and prev for each instance of .tile, they appear correctly, however when attempting to use them to select which page to load into their container, it will use the value of next and prev from the last created instances of next and previous, instead of the relevant ones.

What thing did I type wrong?

```
$(".tile").each(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
     container = $("#container");
     button = $this.find(".button")
     next = button.data("next");
     prev = button.data("prev");
     urls = ["i.html", "b/i.html", "p/i.html"]

 button.on({
  mousedown: function(){
   console.log(urls[next])
    container.empty().load(urls[next])
   }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not instantiating `next` and `prev` as new variables for each iteration of the loop. That means in total exactly 1 version of `next` and `prev` exist in your entire program and you just keep re-assigning a value to it. Every button listener you make will refer to this same `next` variable. Use the `var` keyword inside your loop:

```
$(".tile").each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var container = $("#container");
     var button = $this.find(".button")
     var next = button.data("next");
     var prev = button.data("prev");
     var urls = ["i.html", "b/i.html", "p/i.html"]

     button.on({
      mousedown: function(){
       console.log(urls[next])
        container.empty().load(urls[next])
      }
     })
})
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was under the impression using var initially in a list of var's instantiated them all.

Comment: @user1429671 I've been there before too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed your code:

```
// Those two are unnecessary inside the each. Use before the each loop 
var $container = $("#container"),               // use comma while listing variables!
    urls = ["i.html", "b/i.html", "p/i.html"];  // Close listing using ;

$(".tile").each(function(){

  var $this = $(this),                 // use comma while listing variables!
      $button = $this.find(".button"),
      next = $button.data("next"),
      prev = $button.data("prev");     // Close listing using ;

  $button.on({
     mousedown: function(){
       console.log(urls[next]);
       $container.empty().load(urls[next]);
     }
  });

});
```